# window.postMessage fires the message event twice after upgrading firefox version 68.0 or beta version also

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

when I fire window.postMessage method in firefox 68.0v or beta version only once, but this message is triggering twice in the firefox extension

window.postMessage( { 'type':'sbCheckExtension'}, '*' );

It should fire only once